# How do I allow the opening of all applications from a specific website?

Tags: applications, macos, security, data-transfer

I frequently download from an unidentified developer, and I want to be able to always allow opening downloads from them. How can I do so?

However, I don't want to keep an option to allow apps downloaded from anywhere, although on a side note that option seems to have strangely disappeared.

Comment: I don't think that is possible.  There is a reason it is called an "unidentified developer."  How do you plan to identify the difference between the 2?

Comment: @William I'd think their is some way. At the very least, mark a certain website safe.

Comment: Where do you think the website data or url would be stored?  I would 1st ask a question how to disable it either per download or universally but that is just my 2 cents.

Comment: @William You used to be able to allow downloads from anywhere, but they recently removed the option. Anyways, it's not what I desire.

Comment: 'Anywhere' is still an option for me in Sierra, though I have heard others mention it's gone. Maybe the simplest alternative is just the regular 'right click > Open' for first launch ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the only option I'm aware of:

1. Navigate to 'System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General'
2. Click the lock on the bottom left of the window and enter an admin password
3. Click the radio button that says 'Anywhere'
4. Click the lock in the bottom left of the window again to prevent further changes

You would have to remember to go back and change it though when you're done downloading applications from that specific website/developer. Yes, it's a pain, but you could set a reminder for yourself with a date on it so that your Mac can remind you to change it back at a certain time!